# Select all rows that contain a set of value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I would like to select all IDs that contain a variable set of values.

With data as :

| ID | TYPE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 5 |
| 1 | a | 10 |
| 1 | b | 20 |
| 1 | a | 30 |
| 1 | b | 50 |
| 1 | a | 40 |
| 2 | a | 10 |
| 2 | b | 50 |
| 2 | b | 20 |
| 2 | a | 20 |
| 3 | a | 30 |
| 3 | b | 50 |
| 3 | b | 20 |
| 3 | a | 10 |
| 3 | a | 80 |
| 4 | a | 10 |
| 5 | b | 50 |

---

**a** and **b** can contain a variable set of values (here 2 values each but can be 1 for **a** and 4 for **b** like a filter) :

Ex : **b** in (20,50) and **a** in (10,30)

Result :

| ID | TYPE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 5 |
| 1 | a | 10 |
| 1 | b | 20 |
| 1 | a | 30 |
| 1 | b | 50 |
| 1 | a | 40 |
| 3 | a | 30 |
| 3 | b | 50 |
| 3 | b | 20 |
| 3 | a | 10 |
| 3 | a | 80 |

Comment: Can you also show us your current query attempt?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an aggregation approach for **b** in (20,50) and **a** in (10,30)

```sql
SELECT ID
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN a = 10 THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN a = 30 THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN b = 20 THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN b = 50 THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Tim. As a said, **a** and **b** are dynamique and can contain a variable number of values. They can be null or contain multiples values. This is the reason why I encounter some difficuties :)

Comment: @MaximeMkhe Great.  My answer is meeting your requirements.  I don't know what else you want here.

Comment: I believe the OP is saying that the required values (10 and 30 for a, and 20 and 50 for b) are dynamic, they are not known at the time the query is written. He didn't tell us **how** those values are passed in to the query.

Comment: In addition to how you plan on passing the list of values for `a` and `b` do they **always** contain exactly 2 element?

Answer (score 0):

I'd filter the table to just values being searched for (which mimics `a=x or a=y`) then use a having clause to assert all values must be present (mimicking AND logic rather than OR).

```
WITH
  filter_values AS
(
  SELECT
    id, type
  FROM
    your_table
  WHERE
       (type = 'a' AND value IN (10, 30))
    OR (type = 'b' AND value IN (20, 50))
  GROUP BY
    id, type
  HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT value) = CASE type WHEN 'a' THEN 2 WHEN 'b' THEN 2 END
)
SELECT
  id
FROM
  filter_values
GROUP BY
  id
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = 2
```

Note, however, that this type of search pattern can get quite slow on large tables.  Without changing your schema, it's unavoidable. (Search the Web for why Entity-Attribute-Value tables are good for dynamic storage but poor for dynamic search.)